# SQL Server 2005 Weird varchar Behavior

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

This SQL Server 2005 T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @Test1 varchar;
SET @Test1 = 'dog';

DECLARE @Test2 varchar(10);
SET @Test2 = 'cat';

SELECT @Test1 AS Result1, @Test2 AS Result2;
```

produces:

**Result1 = d
Result2 = cat**

I would expect either

1. The assignment `SET @Test1 =
   'dog';` to fail because there isn't
   enough room in `@Test1`
2. Or the `SELECT` to return 'dog' in the Result1 column.

What is up with `@Test1`?  Could someone please explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer with some quotes from the SQL Server documentation.

#### char and varchar

> **varchar[(n)]**
>
> ...
>
> When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

#### Converting Character Data

> When character expressions are converted to a character data type of a different size, values that are too long for the new data type are truncated.

So, your varchar is declared as a `varchar(1)`, and the implicit conversion in your `SET` statement (from a string literal of length 3 to a `varchar(1)`) truncates `dog` to `d`.

Answer (score 0):

the varchar is defaulting to length one

```
DECLARE @Test1 varchar;
```

try this, which will uses a simple function that takes a sql_variant and returns the data type info back:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[yourFunction]
(
     @InputStr      sql_variant   --can not be varchar(max) or nvarchar(max)
)
returns
varchar(8000)

BEGIN
    DECLARE @Value varchar(50)
    --can use SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType') to determine given datatype

    --do whatever you want with @inputStr here
    IF @InputStr IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @value= 'was null'
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='varchar'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'varchar('+CONVERT(varchar(10),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'MaxLength '))+') - '+CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='datetime'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'datetime - '+CONVERT(char(23),@InputStr,121)
    END
    ELSE IF SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'BaseType')='nvarchar'
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        SET @value= 'nvarchar('+CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(int,SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@InputStr,'MaxLength '))/2)+') - '+CONVERT(varchar(8000),@InputStr)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        --your special code here
        set @value= 'unknown!'
    END

    RETURN  @value

END
GO

DECLARE @Test1 varchar;
SET @Test1 = 'dog';

DECLARE @Test2 varchar(10);
SET @Test2 = 'cat';

SELECT @Test1 AS Result1, @Test2 AS Result2;

select [dbo].[yourFunction](@test1)
```

output:

```
Result1 Result2
------- ----------
d       cat

(1 row(s) affected)


-------------------
varchar(1) - d

(1 row(s) affected)
```

moral of the story, **don't be lazy, specify a length on all of your varchar values!!!**