# T-SQL Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, uniqueidentifier

How can I fix this error?

#### Code

```
declare @guid uniqueidentifier = '4164980A-EFD0-4C60-A18A-253465E00E9C'

print 'GUID ='+cast(@guid as varchar)
```

#### Result

> Msg 8170, Level 16, State 2, Line 2 
>   Insufficient result space to convert uniqueidentifier value to char.

Comment: Specify length for your `VARCHAR` otherwise it'll default to 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 Weird varchar Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676016/sql-server-2005-weird-varchar-behavior)

Comment: Read [bad habits to kick: varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) by Aaron Bertrand. The whole blog "bad habits to kick" is quite readworthy ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a string length for your `varchar` variable, otherwise the default length will be 30 (which is not long enough to contain your value), as per Microsoft documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **varchar [ ( n | max ) ] Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000.**
>
> When n is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30.

So the following should resolve your problem:

```
declare @guid uniqueidentifier = '4164980A-EFD0-4C60-A18A-253465E00E9C'
print 'GUID ='+cast(@guid as varchar(36))
```

Comment: Reading a little farther in the cited documentation: "When _n_ is not specified when using the CAST and CONVERT functions, the default length is 30." Still not long enough for a GUID and still a bad practice.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I quoted the wrong part of the documentation - I missed that the OP here was using `cast`. I will edit, thanks.

Comment: @HABO, took the words out of my mouth. But I think OP's thinking about using `VARCHAR` without a length specified for a T-SQL variable (eg: `declare @stringVar varchar`). In this case it definitely will have only 1-char length.